# Javascript equivalent of bash read -p

Tags: javascript, bash

In order to get familiar with javascript and eventually explore the possible to restify the js script, i'm trying to convert a bash script into a javascript (with the intent on running the js the same way i'd run the bash script).  So far i've been able to replicate most of bash functionnality in js except for parameter prompts.

For example, in bash I prompt the script user for parameter this way:

```
read -p "Are you a god? (Y/N) " ANSWER
```

with the effect that whatever input the user enter will be stored in variable ANSWER

from the i can continue with my script with something like this:

```
if [ "$ANSWER" = "Y" ]; then echo "You lying puny human"; else echo "Then die!"; fi
```

Now, i've looked at various options that javascript offer like the readline module or the prompt module but unless i'm missing something from the examples provided in the documentation

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline  for readline and
https://github.com/flatiron/prompt for prompt

It looks like it would do what i'm looking for but when i try that in an actual script, i can't seem to get my variable outside of the scope of the prompt/readline function

for example if i try this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log('Thank you for your valuable feedback:', answer);

  rl.close();
});

echo(answer);
```

i'll get an error saying that the answer variable used in the echo is not declared

if i try this instead:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var result
rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  result = answer
  console.log('Thank you for your valuable feedback:', answer);

  rl.close();
});

echo(result);
```

the echo will be resolved when the prompt occurs and i'll see an undefined being echoed on my prompt line and then i'll be able to provide a value to the prompt and then once the prompt is resolved the script will end

My examples are using readline module but i pretty much got the same results with prompt

so to resummarize my question after this lenghty context:
can i get somewhat the same behavior in javascript that i get in bash using read -p  in the sense that i have some script being run, then it pause to prompt the user then it carry on with the rest of the script?

Comment: move your echo command to inside the readline callback, where _answer_ is available...

Comment: I used echo in this case to just have a command outside of the callback because that's the behaviour i have in bash.  readline -p store the input of the prompt in the provided variable then i can use it as i see fit in the rest of my script.  If moving it inside the callback is indeed the only option that would mean that i would need to have the rest of my script within the callback in order to be able to use the prompt result elsewhere.  If that's the case, it would at least indicate me to stop looking as i cannot replicate this bash behavior in javascript

Comment: You do need to hookup inside the callback, but you can call a function from there instead of pasting "the rest" in there. This leads to a better design 9/10 times anyway, even if giving up the "top-down" readability. Make each big chunk of the app a function that calls the next one, passing along needed data.

Comment: I do see your point in placing a function call in the callback instead of like 30 line of codes but then i'll ask this in order to have a more or less complete answer to my original question:  can i get the prompt result outside of the prompt scope by any means?

Comment: Sure, you can publish it to a global, but the problem is more a matter of _when_ than _where_: you'de still have to somehow wait for the response before continuing, and a callback is the perfect way of doing that.

Comment: Alright, thx for that, now if you would be so kind as to post it as an answer, i'll be able to accept it